# Want to override a setting in php.ini file

Tags: php, apache

I want to uncomment the below setting in `php.ini` file. But i don't have access to the server, I only have cpanel access. I want this setting to be changed for my current project only. Please help me how can I do this?

change

```
;extension=php_fileinfo.dll
```

to

```
extension=php_fileinfo.dll
```

Comment: Ask to your hosting provider.

Comment: So, to clarify, you have FTP access or not?

Comment: Yes i have FTP and cpanel access.